# Maintain scroll position on new page load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to achieve the same result you see in the w3schools website. 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

When you click a link in the left, side nav it opens the page of the link you clicked, but it also maintains the previous scroll position of the left side nav, with the active link in focus.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by scroll the left bar to the active item position. `scrollTo` is the method to use. [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp) further information.

jQuery has a method that [scroll](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/). this can be used by the animation method to do it smoother.[here](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2) a reference.